# How to change LUFA default 8MHz crystal setting?

Tags: usb, avr, crystal, atmega32u4, lufa

I have an [Atmega32u4](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf) micro controller with minimum hardware design. It has an embedded USB compatibility which can be enable/used with some software like [LUFA](https://github.com/abcminiuser/lufa/).

Everything works fine (the computer detects the device as I defined in [descriptor](https://github.com/abcminiuser/lufa/blob/master/Demos/Device/ClassDriver/Keyboard/Descriptors.c) file and [makefile](https://github.com/abcminiuser/lufa/blob/master/Demos/Device/ClassDriver/Keyboard/makefile)) with 8MHz, setting in the **makefile** line 83:

```
F_CPU = 8000000
```

I also set the fuse bit settings of the microcontroller to use the internal 8MHz clock.

When I use a 16MHz crystal and set the low fuse bit to 111 (datasheet page 30) to use the 16MHz oscillation, and change the F_CPU line of the makefile to 16000000, the computer doesn't recognize the USB anymore.

I didn't disconnect from the microcontroller. I can change the setting back, so I assumed there is something that I should change in the code of LUFA. Is there anywhere else to modify the code to use 16MHz crystal?

PS:

1. The USB port is providing 5 volt power for the micro controller.
2. I am modifying the [keyboard file](https://github.com/abcminiuser/lufa/tree/master/Demos/Device/ClassDriver/Keyboard) of LUFA.
3. I tested the microcontroller with small blinking program and 16MHZ crystal, and it blinks, but no luck on LUFA.
4. I uploaded the Arduino Leonardo bootloader(which works fine with 16MHz) to the chip, and it works perfectly, but I don't like to use Arduino code.

Comment: What is the supply voltage of your ATmega32U4, 5V, or does it run at 3.3V? Better yet, show the schematics.

Comment: this may or may not help ... check this directory in the arduino IDE ... `arduino-1.8.12\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\caterina`